# Drupal 7 FAQ with domain access module?

Tags: drupal

I have a following problems:

I have installed Domain Access and FAQ_Ask (https://www.drupal.org/project/faq_ask) modules on my website and I have two sub domains named bg02 and bg03.

I want users assigned to different domains to publish questions only on their assigned domain and respectively Experts assigned to each domain to answer questions only published to their domain. On content type FAQ I have Domain access settings:

Publish to: Author's currently active domain
I use Domain Bonus: Login restict module in order users to be logged only to their assigned domain and I have roles “FAQ ask user bg02” and “FAQ ask user bg03” with permissions:

FAQ: Create new content on assigned domains
Faq_Ask - Ask a question

View FAQ pages
View own unpublished content
FAQ: Edit own content
and roles “expert bg02” and “expert bg03” with persmissions:
Publish content to any assigned domain
View unpublished content on assigned domains
FAQ: Edit any content on assigned domains

Faq_Ask - Answer a question
View FAQ pages

On Administration » Structure » Domains USER DEFAULTS tab (admin/structure/domain/roles) I have:

FAQ ASK USER BG02 assigned to domain bg02 and
FAQ ASK USER BG03 assigned to domain bg03
EXPERT BG02 assigned to domain bg02 and
EXPERT BG03 assigned to domain bg03

On Frequently Asked Questions configuration page(admin/config/content/faq/ask) I have Expert Roles “expert bg02” and “expert bg03” and some categories assigned to the experts.

But when an expert logs into an assigned domain, he can see all the unanswered questions no matter of the domain or category term. When for example “expert bg02” clicks on a question posted by “user bg03” he gets a message “Access denied”, but the question is still published to the domain bg03.

Is there a way the experts to see only the questions that have to be published to their domain or at least the publishing status of the question to not change to “published” when the expert opens it?

Also I have noticed that only the default expert receives a notification email on unanswered questions. Is there a way all the experts to receive notification emails?

Thank You for the support!

Answer (score 1):

This may be the problem with setting file that in sub domain  folder:

*

> $cookie_domain = '.drupalgoodsite.com';

*
by this way Domain Share can access you are Main Domains Module by default .